# mac OS looking for nonexistent path to g++ after update to High Sierra 10.13.1

Tags: c++, macos, g++

I got the following error when trying to run g++ from the command line (worked in Makefile):

```
$ g++ main.cpp
-bash: /usr/local/bin/g++-6: No such file or directory
```

I have a directory named `/usr/local/bin/g++-7`. Changing the directory name to `g++-6` solved the problem, but I'm confused on why the OS didn't know to look for `g++-7`.

How can I tell my mac to look for `/usr/local/bin/g++-7` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a symlink/alias issue somewhere on your machine. If I were you I would update with homebrew.  That *should* fix your issue in a correct/permanent way.

You can also try to create an alias to g++-7 however this would need to be done anytime you update gcc/g++. To do this, open `~/.bash_profile` in vim/nano/emacs/textmate (your choice here really) and add:

```
alias g++='g++-7'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! The issue was an alias to g++-6 in my .bash_profile.

Comment: @EricMajidian No problem!